# Laravel dusk + docker-compose + selenium + firefox: Undefined index ELEMENT

Tags: selenium, firefox, docker-compose, laravel-dusk

I have docker-compose with 3 images - `webserver`, `db` and `selenium`.

I up it then exec into webserver and run `php artisan dusk`.

My app is a simple https page that returns `Welcome` in a few `div`.
But I got `ErrorException: Undefined index: ELEMENT`.

Selenium `image: selenium/standalone-firefox`.

```
test:
...
$this->browse(function (Browser $browser) use ($user) {
  $browser
    ->visit('/home')
    ->assertSee('Welcome');
});


DuskTestCase.php
...
protected function driver() {
  return RemoteWebDriver::create(
    'http://selenium:4444/wd/hub', DesiredCapabilities::firefox()->setCapability(
      'acceptInsecureCerts', true
    )
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to an incompatibility between the geckodriver and Selenium:

https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver/issues/492

For Firefox and Selenium you need to add `enablePassThrough=false` to the Selenium capabilities.

Something like:

```
protected function driver() {
  return RemoteWebDriver::create(
    'http://selenium:4444/wd/hub', DesiredCapabilities::firefox()
        ->setCapability('acceptInsecureCerts', true)
        ->setCapability('enablePassThrough', false)
  );
}
```

should probably do the trick.